# SQL ORDER BY with specific order, start with particular word first then followed by ascending order

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I want an output like first name of employees in ascending order, but it should start with name  'jack' then rest of the name in ascending order'.

Output should be like this,

```
Jack
Anto
Becky
Carrry
Dominic
Emil
.
.
....
zen
```

Answer (score 6):

Please try

```
Select firstname from employees Order by 
case when firstname like 'jack' then 0 else 1 end, firstname ASC
```

SQL Fiddle demo at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/768d0/10

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the below query

```
SELECT 
     myname
FROM 
     names
ORDER BY
     myname not like 'jack',
     myname;
```

demo at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/768d0/20